# numba cuda on matrix decomposition code in python

Tags: python, cuda, numerical-methods, numba

I'm trying to implement this code to use my gpu

```
import numpy as np
import math
import numba
from numba import vectorize , cuda

@cuda.jit(['float32(float 32)'], device=True)
def CholeskyInc(A):
    n,m = A.shape
    
    if n!=m:
        print('La matriz no es cuadrada')
    else:
        
        L = np.zeros((n,n))
        
        for k in range(n):
            L[k,k] = math.sqrt(A[k,k])
            for i in range(k+1,n):
                if A[i,k] != 0:
                    L[i,k]=A[i,k]/A[k,k]
                
            for j in range(k+1,n):
                for i in range(j,n):
                    if A[i,j] != 0:
                        L[i,j] = A[i,j]-A[i,k]*A[j,k]
    return L
```

Actually, I don't have any experience using numba and I prove some options but any of them work yet. Does anyone could explainme how I can execute this code in the GPU rather than the CPU using numba and cuda.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking -- the code you have written is already "implemented  to use my gpu". It is a CUDA device function. You can call it from any Numba CUDA kernel you want.

Comment: I think that something is missing because when i execute the code it only runs over cpu

Comment: That code is a function definition. That is all it is. Do you actually understand elementary Python syntax? And the concept that you have to *call* a function for it to do something? And, as I noted in my first comment -- this function is a device function, meaning that you *must* call it from within a Numba CUDA kernel

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel: Cholesky factorization is already implemented in several libraries such as [CuSolver](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/index.html) which will likely be much faster than your Numba implementation (and probably less bug prone).

Comment: I would narrow down the question - (1) how to run *any* python script on GPU - answer eg. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/running-python-script-on-gpu/ (2) what are the concrete problems you encountered while trying to implement (1)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the needed rep here to just comment, so here's a couple suggestions to start:

1. The decorator usage:

   - Usin `@cuda.jit` as a decorator lets you skip defining the arg types and return type of your function.
   - You only need to call `@cuda.jit(device=True)` if you plan on calling this function from another cuda kernel function. Where a cuda kernel function is any function where you haven't set `device=True`. See the code sample at the end of this response.
2. Functions compiled to cuda kernels can't have an explicit return, nor can they print to console.

   - In place of returning `L`, create L in the host code (the code you are running on cpu) and pass that `L` as a second parameter to your function. After you run the function the results will be stored in `L`.
   - In place of the print statement you'll have to do something like assign an error value to `L` and check for that error value before you later use `L`

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import cuda
from math import sqrt

def main():
    """ Creates 2 matrices with randomized values which are then
    passed to a cuda kernel where the incomplete Cholesky factorization
    is done.

    these first several lines set up the input arrays (your A and L)
    as well as the thread and block shape that numba will need when
    launching your kernel onto the GPU.
    """
    np.set_printoptions(linewidth=240)
    rand_n = np.random.randint(8 ,11)
    A = np.random.random((rand_n ,rand_n)).astype(np.float32)
    L = np.zeros((A.shape[0] ,A.shape[0]) ,dtype=A.dtype)
    #       tpb meaning "threads per block"
    tpb_y = 16
    tpb_x = 16
    tpb = tpb_x ,tpb_y
    #       bpg meaning "blocks per grid"
    bpg_y = (A.shape[0] + tpb_y -1 )//tpb_y # ensures enough blocks to cover whole matrix height
    bpg_x = (A.shape[1] + tpb_x -1 )//tpb_x # ensures enough blocks to cover whole matrix width
    #   Alternatively, you could use the following commented lines
    #   which will allocate fewer thread-blocks (less overhead) but requires that
    #   we implement striding loops in our kernel/device functions to
    #   cover the rest of the matrix data.
    # bpg_y = (A.shape[0]//2 + tpb_y-1)//tpb_y # cover half of matrix height, and stride the other half
    # bpg_x = (A.shape[1]//2 + tpb_x-1)//tpb_x # cover half of matrix width, and stride the other half
    bpg = bpg_x ,bpg_y
    # now we launch the kernel
    my_cuda_kernel[bpg ,tpb](A ,L)
    if np.isnan(L[0 ,0]):
        print('La matriz no es cuadrada')
    print(f"A:\n{A}")
    print(f"L:\n{L}")

@cuda.jit
def my_cuda_kernel(arr_in :np.ndarray, arr_out :np.ndarray):
    # in your kernel, you can set up shared memory
    # or implement looping structures to stride through global device memory.
    n ,m = arr_in.shape
    if n!= m:
        # set the first element on the diagonal to a NaN value,
        # as a way to signal that no operations were done on L.
        arr_out[0, 0] = np.nan  # check by calling np.isnan(L[0,0])
        return

    # get the current thread's location within the grid
    x, y = cuda.grid(2)  # 2 because we launched the kernel specifying only x, and y dimensions

    # these x,y coordinates don't explicitly map to coordinates in the array objects
    # but we can simplify our indexing by treating them like they do.
    x_stride, y_stride = cuda.gridsize(2)

    # this loop provides 2 purposes:
    #   1. It acts as boundary check to make sure we don't attempt to read
    #      memory locations outside of the input/output arrays.
    #   2. It also allows our threads to "stride" through the data, and do more
    #      work to justify the overhead cost setting this thread-block up.
    #           * Note that threads will only be able to "stride"
    #             if we don't launch the kernel with full grid coverage.
    for _k in range(0, n, x_stride * y_stride):
        k = _k + y
        # we are telling each thread to stride the
        # diagonal and compute the cholesky for arr[:,k] rows and arr[k,:] cols.
        CholeskyInc(arr_in, arr_out, n, k)


@cuda.jit(device=True)
def CholeskyInc(A, L, n, k):
    L[k, k] = sqrt(A[k, k])
    for i in range(k + 1, n):
        if A[i, k] != 0:
            L[i, k] = A[i, k] / L[k, k]
    for j in range(k + 1, n):
        for i in range(j, n):
            if A[i, j] != 0:
                L[i, j] = A[i, j] - A[i, k] * A[j, k]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

which produces the following output:

```
A:
[[0.29083535 0.80408204 0.63088804 0.90458757 0.86371994 0.7966909  0.5818828  0.8885034 ]
 [0.24579939 0.8107     0.9785071  0.40308124 0.96477604 0.39282414 0.18642609 0.3129212 ]
 [0.18401423 0.11662608 0.3512116  0.97926706 0.4021766  0.23531164 0.81310475 0.93359345]
 [0.5243785  0.0469533  0.49699584 0.507422   0.24569689 0.4899143  0.61420184 0.9332651 ]
 [0.1070556  0.5214806  0.24065676 0.8860097  0.5074029  0.43745205 0.09919663 0.9222924 ]
 [0.17103161 0.25640044 0.94678307 0.26446953 0.9416109  0.8391528  0.69582105 0.5433431 ]
 [0.5520146  0.10083573 0.7929039  0.44067022 0.6251738  0.6831893  0.23636419 0.97260725]
 [0.47044474 0.13215688 0.5002679  0.72581047 0.8298903  0.55161124 0.6673608  0.5644971 ]]
L:
[[ 0.5392915   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.45578206  0.75028265  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.34121478  0.07139549  0.31735036  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.972347   -0.08193862  0.40050274  0.23244919  0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.19851157  0.49516642  0.22095701  0.829872    0.495942    0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.3171413   0.21436097  0.9153108   0.17478424  0.923301    0.809901    0.          0.        ]
 [ 1.0235922  -0.03484913  0.69132537  0.15120566  0.56607753  0.5887773  -0.06835592  0.        ]
 [ 0.8723385   0.01652185  0.4136994   0.47911936  0.7795266   0.47115034  0.4076684   0.34317887]]
```